# XSLT: Set xmlns uri dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xslt, and I need to be able to inject the uri dynamically into an xmlns. I have to use version 1.0.
looking around I found https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200701/msg00185.html which seems to show how to do what I want to do, but, I was unable to figure out how to do it

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                >
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:param name="someparam">
   <xsl:param uri=dynamic uri>
   <xsl:template name="envelope" match="/">
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://sxhemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                     xmlns:some="http://someurl"
                     xmlns:dynamic="dynamically injected uri"
                     xmlns:dynamic2="dynamically injected uri">
          <soapenv:Header>
              <some:Data>
              </Data>
          </soapenv:Header>
          <soapenv:Body>
              <dynamic:methodCall>
                  <dynamic2:Param><xsl:value-of select="$someparam"/></dynamic2:Param>
              </dynamic:methodCall>
          </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i want to some how set the uri for dynamic and dynamic2

Comment: I don't think this is possible in XSLT 1.0. The method described in the linked page would allow you to select a namespace from a "bank" of known namespaces at most. For a completely "dynamic" namespace you would need to start by generating a new stylesheet (see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#literal-result-element) then using the result to transform your input. Why do you need this? It is very unusual to construct a stylesheet when the target schema is not known in advance.

Comment: @michael.hor, its probably for bad reasons, but, there several xlst files in a project I am working on that all are accessing the same uri, we have to deal with "version" changes in uri (different team. can't be stopped) that usually don't result in us having to modify anything in the xlst files other then a version number. What I am trying to do is reduce the number of places where I need to change the version number down to one place. if there isn't any way to do it in xlst, then i'll  just load the files and swap the version numbers

Comment: Doesn't the answer below meet your requirement?

Comment: I was on old page when i submitted the answer, it definitely does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following simplified example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="dyn-uri">example.com/123</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://sxhemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <xsl:element name="dynamic:methodCall" namespace="{$dyn-uri}">
                <xsl:value-of select="123"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In most, if not all XSLT processors, this will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://sxhemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dynamic:methodCall xmlns:dynamic="example.com/123">123</dynamic:methodCall>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This result is semantically identical to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://sxhemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dynamic="example.com/123">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <dynamic:methodCall>123</dynamic:methodCall>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

which seems to be the result you expect. Any conforming XML parser will parse these two documents into an identical tree.